# C++ "Program has stopped working"

Tags: c++

I am working on a program for class. The program compiles but when I enter a value for length a window pops up saying "Pipeprogram.exe has stopped working". It then goes on to say "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available".

So far with a couple of google searches I have found no solution. If anyone could help out it would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to scanf, using an &. So,

```
scanf("%f", &length);
```

Comment: Also, modern compilers are able to warn about this error, so try turning up the warning level

Comment: FYI, the last Dev-cpp IDE shipped with Mingw/GCC 3.4.2 (which was released 2004-September-6). As of 2014-December-19 the current version of GCC is 4.8.4. For windows users, `MinGW-w64` and/or `CygWin` provide a straightforward way to get an up-to-date gcc compiler.